# JST String comparision Issue

Tags: string, comparison, jstl

I used JSTL expression a lot. But today, I got a really weird issue. I have two expressions.

```
 1.${(tc.firmApproval.processStatus2)}
 2.${tc.firmApproval.processStatus2 eq 'APPROVED'}
```

and the results are

```
1. APPROVED
2. false
```

if I replace the second one as

```
   2.${'APPROVED' eq 'APPROVED'},
```

the result is **true**

I have no idea why the original second expression does not work. Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of `processStatus2`? Can you try `${tc.firmApproval.processStatus2.toString() eq 'APPROVED'}`?

Comment: The type of processStatus2 is string. The issue disappeared after I restarted Eclipse.